# missing parameter value in sub report when its datatable is empty

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have crystal report reading data from procedure1 take courseID as parameter, I insert sub report in that report reading data from procedure2 also take courseID as a parameter, when procedure2 return result the main report work fine and both main and sub report display but when procedure2 return no result the main report show me "missing parameter value" error
any help???

Answer (score 0):

Set your parameter to optional in the parameter settings.

**Right Click** the desired parameter in the main report choose **Edit...** and toggle the **Optional Prompt** to true.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for helping, but "optional prompt" is disabled I cant change it to true